# Eccentricity estimation in Python

Tags: python, pca

I've got a binary numpy array and have labeled the connected regions with scipy.ndimage. Is there a call that I can make to estimate the eccentricity of each labeled section?

Edit:

I'm trying to develop criteria to find and toss the labeled sections that are much longer than they are wide. In the following array, I might want to keep the 7s and toss the 3s.

```
3 3 0 0 0 0
3 3 0 7 7 7
3 3 0 7 7 7
3 3 0 7 0 7
3 3 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What is your definition of eccentricity? You have a 2D array? You want to work on the tensor of inertia of you points?

Comment: Eccentricity as a measure of how enlongated each labeled blob is. It's a 2D array, yes. It'd be nice if it could also work for 3, though that could be for later.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you first need a bit of math. Let first consider you have only one blob labeled as 1. Your matrix label will be a scalar field.
You should first compute its average:

[image: mean]

where [image: rho] is your label (it as no index since it is a scalar).
Then compute:

[image: tensor]

A good definition of eccentricity would be the ratio of the two biggest eigenvalues of the traceless part of this matrix (in 2D, you will have only 2 eigenvalues). You can also normalize it to get a value between 0 and 1.
I am not used enough with scipy to write an efficient code for that.

Comment: This would be perfect. My gut tells me it's just a couple of calls with scipy, but I have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you assign each label only once: a matrix with an eccentric blob will have more empty rows than empty column or vice versa.

```py
labels = [2,3,7] # or whatever you have
good_labels = []
for label in labels:
    m = matrix == label
    non_empty_columns = sum(sum(m)>0)
    non_empty_rows = sum(sum(m.transpose())>0)
    if 1.0 * non_empty_rows / (non_empty_columns+0.001) > threshold:
        good_labels.append(label)
```

That will remove very long (vertically) blobs, turn rows and columns around to remove horizontally stretched blobs.

Comment: In many cases this would work, but what about cases like a 'T' shape?